# ExpandableListView is not expend in android

Tags: android, android-layout

my layout contain expandable listview and some ImageView. It's works fine but my expandablelistview is not open on click:-

here my xml:-

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">



  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
   android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">

     <include
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <ExpandableListView
     android:id="@+id/list_track_list_activity_sub_category"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:divider="#b5b5b5"
     android:dividerHeight="1dp"
     android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>

    <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/sub_banners1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:paddingTop="10dp"
     android:paddingLeft="10dp"
     android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

    <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/sub_banners2"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:paddingTop="10dp"
     android:paddingLeft="10dp"
     android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

    <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/sub_banners3"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingTop="10dp"
     android:paddingLeft="10dp"
     android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

    <FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/container_body"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="1" />



   </LinearLayout>

   </ScrollView>


   <fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.shoppingmazza.activity.FragmentDrawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Here my java:-

```
expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.list_track_list_activity_sub_category);
    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapterForMenu(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        // Listview on child click listener
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : hmap.entrySet()) {
                if (entry.getValue().equals(listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition))) {
                    sendMenu_id = String.valueOf(entry.getKey());
                    break;
                }
            }

            Intent i = new Intent(SubCategory.this, ProductsCategory.class);
            i.putExtra("category", sendMenu_id);
            startActivity(i);

            return false;
        }
    });
    expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
        }
    });

    expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {

        }
    });
```

and My Adapter class:-

```
public class ExpandableListAdapterForMenu extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

public ExpandableListAdapterForMenu(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                             HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

    String content = childText;
    content = content.replace("&#039;", "");
    content = content.replace("&amp;","&");
    txtListChild.setText(content);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

    String content =     headerTitle;
    content = content.replace("&#039;", "");
    content = content.replace("&amp;","&");
    lblListHeader.setText(content);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

In my java code i change my imageview heigth programmatically.

Anyone tell me how can i solved this problem.Thanks is advance!

Comment: to help you we need to see your adapter and the part of your activity where you add data to adapter.

Comment: see my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

inside `onGroupExpand` add `expListView.expandGroup(groupPosition);` 
and inside `onGroupCollapse` add `expListView.collapseGroup(groupPosition);`

Comment: ok try remove setOnGroupExpandListener and setOnGroupCollapseListener methods you dont need them

Comment: and the problem is that you dont have childs you cant use this this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);

Comment: instead use this._listDataChild.get(childPosition);